# Tkinter window not responding after destroy() - macOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

The goal is for the user to choose a file and then the program to process it:

```
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
root.destroy()

# Long running process after this...
```

This works fine in windows, but in mac it leaves a Python app not responding in the dock bar after `root.destroy()`.

[image: Application Not Responding]

The program still runs in the background and process the file, but I wonder if this "Not responding" app in the dock can be removed or hidden after `root.destroy()`.

My setup:

- Python 2.7.17 and 3.7.5.
- macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: Does it will be not responding after user select a file?

Comment: The user manages to select the file and then the Python app goes into "Not responding" but the script keeps running in the background and processing the file.

Comment: Try `root.quit()`

Comment: The same happens with quit()

Comment: You get a "not responding" message because that is exactly what is happening - the program is running but it's not responding to the user.

Comment: But if it has been destroyed then why is the application icon still being shown in the dock?